# Fetch 5 records again and again from data base

Tags: php, android, sql

I am developing an `android` app where i want to fetch 5 records each time using this query.

```
SELECT *from contest_table WHERE created_by='$me' LIMIT 5;
```

Now i get 5 records , but i want to fetch more 5 (next) records from data base when i click on "FETCH-MORE-RECORD" button inside the app

Comment: I think you are searching for pagination..

Comment: You can use `LIMIT` with `OFFSET`

Comment: Which Database engine you are using

Comment: @frz3993 i am using limit to fetch 5 records each time, but how to fetch next-5 record when again, please help me

Comment: @Anant ($last_id+5) mean to fetch next 5 records?

Comment: sorry to mis-understood your problem. you have solutions below. check them

Comment: just store the offset in static variable and fire it again with click in query simple

Comment: also update the offset everytime you fire so next time you get right result

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir Yes, brother, i got the idea, Thank you,

Comment: I posted it in answers too. Let me when you need further help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OFFSET :

```
SELECT * from contest_table WHERE created_by='$me' LIMIT 5,5;
```

This will return 5 more rows, from position the 6th row (6-10).

The first number is to declare the start position of the fetch, and the second one is two declare how many to fetch.

This could also be written like this:

```
SELECT * from contest_table WHERE created_by='$me' LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to give a limit start and range. It will look as follows:

```
SELECT *from contest_table WHERE created_by='$me' LIMIT 5, 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

> To get first 5 records

```
SELECT * from contest_table WHERE created_by='$me' LIMIT 0,5;
```

> To get next 5 records

```
SELECT * from contest_table WHERE created_by='$me' LIMIT 6,5;
```

Like wise you can change the starting point increasing it by 5.

Answer (score 1):

So here is the solution. You need to keep the track of the off. So delcare a static variable for store the off. also update the offset after every click so next time you get right result.

```
public static int offset=5;
```

Then use this query with your listener;

```
 SELECT * from contest_table WHERE created_by='$me' LIMIT 5,5;
```

Comment: $var=5;
SELECT *from contest_table WHERE created_by='$me' LIMIT '$var',5")
its not working

Comment: Try this one SELECT *from contest_table WHERE created_by='$me' LIMIT 5,'$var'")

Comment: i solved it. while using this 
"SELECT *from contest_table WHERE created_by='$me' LIMIT $var,5 ");
Just remove '' this and it solved

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple logic, Which I am representing as `PHP` codes, You request for first page from android by including `page 1`. in `URL`

```
http://SITENAME.COM/index.php?task=articles&page=1
```

**You grab the result coming from URL like here**

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
$max = 5; //As you want to retrieve 5 results only
```

**And here define `$start` from where to start retrieving values**

```
$end = $page * $max;
$start = $end+1 - $max;
```

**Your query will be like**

```
SELECT * FROM table order by column desc limit $start, $max //start will be 1 and max value to retrieve will be 5
```

**After that you request `page 2` and URL will be**

```
http://SITENAME.COM/index.php?task=articles&page=2
```

**and again in the query `$start` will be 6 and max value to retrieve will be 5 that is `$max`**

Hope this helps, This is what the logic behind pagination.